# Rails Searchkick with scopes in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, searchkick, scopes

I'm making a search page where I have a couple of filters on the side and I'm trying to integrate them with Searchkick to query products.

These are my scopes I'm using for the products

models/product.rb

```
scope :in_price_range, ->(range) { where("price <= ?", range.first) }    
scope :in_ratings_range, -> (range) { where("average_rating >= ?", range.first) }

def self.with_all_categories(category_ids)
    select(:id).distinct.
    joins(:categories).
    where("categories.id" => category_ids)
end
```

This is where I'm actually calling the scopes

controllers/search_controller.rb

```
@results = Product.search(@query)
@results = @results.with_all_categories(params[:category_ids]) if params[:category_ids].present?
@results = @results.in_price_range(params[:price]) if params[:price].present?
@results = @results.in_ratings_range(params[:rating]) if params[:rating].present?
```

After running it, I get an error saying the searchkick model doesn't have any methods with the name of my scope.

undefined method `with_all_categories' for #Searchkick::Results:0x00007f4521074c30>

How do I use scopes with my search query?

Comment: `range` argument in your scopes `in_price_range` and `in_ratings_range` is not being used properly. If you use only `range.first` in your query, then why passing a whole range?

Comment: Can you show the exact error message?

Comment: The code is currently like that because I'm planning on changing it into an actual range in the future, but for now I'm trying to get it to work

Comment: I'm getting this error message: 
undefined method `with_all_categories' for #<Searchkick::Results:0x00007f4521074c30> @JagdeepSingh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply scopes to Searchkick results with:

```
Product.search "milk", scope_results: ->(r) { in_price_range(params[:price]) }
```

See "Run additional scopes on results" in [the readme](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick).

However, if you apply ActiveRecord `where` filters, it will throw off pagination. For pagination to work correctly, you need to use Searchkick's `where` option:

```
Product.search(query, where: {price_range: 10..20})
```

Comment: Is there a way to get Searchkick's pagination to play nicely with ActiveRecord's where? I have a custom scope that uses joins etc that would be a hassle to reconstruct...

Answer (score 0):

The error (unknown to me at the time of writing this answer) might be because you defined `with_all_categories` as a class method on `Product`, but in your controller you call it on `@results` which must be an `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

Turning it into a `scope` should fix the issue:

Change this:

```
def self.with_all_categories(category_ids)
  select(:id).distinct.
    joins(:categories).
    where("categories.id" => category_ids)
end
```

to:

```
scope :with_all_categories, -> (category_ids) { select(:id).distinct.joins(:categories).where("categories.id" => category_ids) }
```

Comment: I'm also getting the same error with my other scopes though